# c:forEach.items getting repetitively called

Tags: jsp, jsf, seam, richfaces, jstl

Environment: Seam, Richfaces

The following code snippet causes the method getUsers to be called multiple times, how do I avoid this in my application so that it gets called only once.

```
<c:forEach items="#{userHome.getUsers()}" var="_user">
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rule of thumb is to avoid `<c:` tags when using JSF (unless you are sure they work as expected)

Here you'd better repllace it with:

```
<a4j:repeat value="#{userHome.users}" var ="_user">
</a4j:repeat>
```

(or `<ui:repeat>` if using facelets)

P.S. I guess `getUsers()` is JBoss' EL-extension, but I'd suggest not to use its extended features unless really needed.

Answer (score 2):

And for the love of god, if you care about performance ***avoid*** using the EntityHome/Query framework. Just put a breakpoint or output on your `getResultList()` and see how many times it is being called. Now try the same think with a normal seam component. You will see a significant change(!)

Comment: I have seen this behavior where the methods get called many times, isn't the Factory annotation supposed to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thats one approach. You can use Unwrap also. But you can't have factory on all your methods. (You can, but it is not wise).